# Run command in foreground on boot

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, debian-based

I'm running this command to output a log file in the console on a headless Raspberry pi with a screen hooked up to it.

```
$ tail -F /home/pi/Documents/BlackBot-master/bot.log
```

How do I set it up so it runs this command on boot and outputs the log on the screen? Right now I need to enter this command manually each time after it's booted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this help:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md

You can try to add the command in /etc/rc.local. Sometimes you will need to add the absolute path of that command, for example, /usr/bin/tail ... .

Comment: The RPI boots into CLI and doesn't execute the command like normally would if you manually typed it in. That's where i'm trying to get at is running the command and seeing the output as it's visual. 

I tried rc-local.